# good introduction to algebra over a field?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, self-learning

The textbooks on linear algebra that I have read generally don't treat algebras over fields.

Are there any good textbooks that are the "sequels" to a typical linear algebra course, which treat algebras over fields?

Answer (score 2):

The book [An Introduction to Nonassociative Algebras](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486688135) by Richard D. Schafer is a well known book on finite-dimensional algebras over a field. It is written in a plain and clear style, and it reads very smoothly.